# asp.net cannot open SQL Server 2012 database in VS 2013

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have two SQL Server instances on my computer: SQL Server 2008R2 Express and SQL Server 2012 Express. When I try to open a SQL Server 2008 database from Visual Studio it opens. When I try to open a SQL Server 2012 (`(LocalDB)\v11.0`) database, I get the following error. I can open the both databases in Management Studio and in my VS database tool server instance name is `(LocalDB)\v11.0`.

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information:
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Comment: Well, are you sure that LocalDb is installed correctly?  Can you open a LocalDb database in SSMS?

Comment: yes i can open the database with SSMS.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  I said, can you open a LocalDb database in SSMS, ie as a localDb, not as a SQL Express Database... ie, are you connecting to (Localdb)\v11.0\database or are you connecting to MACHINE\Instance\Database?  Note that (local) is not the same as (localdb)

Comment: i cant find local servers with command line "sqlcmd -L"

Comment: Then there you go, your localdb is not installed or configured correctly.  Reinstall it

Comment: i remove both 2008 and 2012 and install 2012 again....the same error

Comment: Are you installing the LocalDb component?